# Insert a value from a form to a table with JAVA EE, JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a list of category characterized by an ID in the database and I want when I choose some category "Catégorie" & insert his value in a checkbox, after click on save i want see this value in a table that contains all values exactly in his place.so to resume i want when i chose a category from list and insert his value see it in the table.Im working with JAVA EE & all this in a page JSP.

Im tried to resolve the problem by doing a test condition by recupere the value of the id category with request.getAttribute("iddd") and test if it equal to "0"(for example) but it doesn't work

```html
<table border="1" id="testTable2" border="1" width=100% class="table table-hover">
 <thead>
 <tr align="center" >
  <th width="50%">Postes</th>
  <th>Poste1 (22h-06h)</th>
  <th>Poste2 (06h-14h)</th>
  <th>Poste3 (14h-22h)</th>
  <th>Total Journé</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 
 <%
UhtBeans stockss;
if(request.getAttribute("stock") != null){
 
 stockss =(UhtBeans) request.getAttribute("stock");
 
}else {
 Operation opers = new Operation();
 stockss = new UhtBeans();
 stockss.setListSt(opers.allStock());
}

%>
   <%
   request.setAttribute("iddd",opp.getAllIdCategorie());
   Iterator<Stock> lists = stockss.getListSt().iterator();
          while(lists.hasNext()){
           Stock s =lists.next();
            
             
   %>
 <tr>
  <th bgcolor="green" class="Date"><%=s.getDate() %></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center" bgcolor="cyan">
  <th>DIAGRAMME TEMPS</th>
  <th>Durée(min)</th>
  <th>Durée(min)</th>
  <th>Durée(min)</th>
  <th>Durée(min)</th>
 </tr>
 <tbody id="colonne">
 <tr align="center">
  <th bgcolor="yellow">Temps Calendrier</th>
  <%int d=480; %>
  <th id="d" class="Duree"><%=d %></th>
  <th ></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 
 <tr align="right">
  <th bgcolor="red">Temps non disponible</th>
  <th class="Duree" id="d11"><%
    System.out.println("ID DU CATEGORIE EST : "+request.getAttribute("iddd"));
  if (request.getAttribute("iddd") == "0"){
   
  %>
  <input type="number" id="d1" class="form-control" value="<%=s.getDuree() %>">
   
   <%} %>
  </th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  
 </tr>
 
 <tr align="center">
  <th bgcolor="yellow">Temps Disponible</th>
  <%int d2; 
  d2=d; %>
  <th><%=d2 %></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="right">
  <th bgcolor="red">Temps disponible non utilisé</th>
  <th  class="Duree">
  <%System.out.println("ID De TDNU EST : "+ request.getAttribute("iddd"));
  if(request.getAttribute("iddd") == "1"){
   %><%=s.getDuree()%>
   <%} %>
  </th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center">
  <th bgcolor="yellow">Temps d'ouverture</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="right">
  <th bgcolor="red">Préventif et révision équipement</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="right">
  <th bgcolor="red">Autres arrêts planifiés non OP</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center">
  <th bgcolor="yellow">Temps operationnel</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="right">
  <th bgcolor="red">Nettoyage</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="right">
  <th bgcolor="red">Autres arrêts OP planifiés</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center">
  <th bgcolor="yellow">Temps de production</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="right">
  <th bgcolor="red">Arrêts organisationnels</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="right">
  <th bgcolor="red">Arrêts techniques</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="right">
  <th bgcolor="red">Arrêts  technologiques</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center">
  <th bgcolor="yellow">Running time</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center">
  <th bgcolor="yellow">Temps net de production</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <%
          }
    %>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with JavaScript? Are you trying to use it somewhere?

Comment: no, im just put it to see if i can do it with JavaScript